# Stream<QuerySnapshot> returns null documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

i have an issue with flutter and cloud-firestore. My Database connection is working and I can create new entries, but my Stream returns null documents.

My database.dart class:

```
final CollectionReference idCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("idCollection");

Future addId(String idName) async {
    return await idCollection
        .document(uid)
        .collection("userIds")
        .document(idName)
        .setData({
      'key': uid + _randomString(6),
    });
}

Stream<QuerySnapshot> get ids {
   return idCollection.snapshots();
}
```

Actually I want the Snapshot to be of the below but since the null error is already thrown for the top collection I am unsure what the problem is.

```
 Stream<QuerySnapshot> get ids {
   return idCollection
        .document(uid)
        .collection("userIds").snapshots();
}
```

The class that wraps the provider

```
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().ids,
```

The error and the class that throws it:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The getter 'documents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: documents
The relevant error-causing widget was
    IdList 
lib\…\home\home.dart:39
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

```
class _IdListState extends State<IdList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ids = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);

    for (var doc in ids.documents) {
      print(doc.data);
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("sdf"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IdList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<IdList> createState() => _IdListState();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if null means you have no data in your collection.works as expected

Answer (score 1):

this is how to query your db using querysnapshot

```
    Future _getUsers() async {
     QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
            .collection('idCollection')
            //you may want to sort your data here 
           
            .getDocuments();
        print('###########s result ${querySnapshot.documents}');

  if (querySnapshot != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.documents.length; i++) {
        var a = querySnapshot.documents[i];
        print(a.documentID);
 setState(() {
          documentId = a.documentID;
         userID = a.data['userId'];
        
        });
```